# How to Insert data with wp cron

Tags: wp-query, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I am using wp_schedule_event for Insert data every 1 Minutes in a teble. But here is some confusion where i have to add code for Insert. 
Here is my code which add in functions.php in my theme.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');
function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'minutes', 'my_hourly_event');

        global $wpdb;
       //INSERT INTO `wp_test`.`wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES (NULL, 'database_options', 'hello', 'yes');
}

function do_this_hourly() {
     $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 60,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 1 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
        );

    return $schedules;
} 

//deactive
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');
function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can to create a schedule for one minute, then bind function with that hook.

```
function add_new_intervals($schedules) 
{
    // add weekly and monthly intervals
    $schedules['every_single_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __('Every Minute')
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'add_new_intervals');

// To schedule event for this minute event
wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'every_single_minutes', 'my_every_minute_event');

//add_action('my_every_minute_event', '_Func_to_execute_');
```

check this [quick reference](http://wpguru.co.uk/2014/01/how-to-create-a-cron-job-in-wordpress-teach-your-plugin-to-do-something-automatically/) for details

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your cron must be register at the plugin or theme activation. Try wp crontol plugin to verify and run your cron task. But, i think you call
 "minutes" interval where you might call "every_three_minutes" interval for the schedule event.